# No such table: core_post

Tags: python, django

Not created the database

[image]

[image]

Although I used the command `migrate`

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` before?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.

Comment: why not send screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following sequence to solve the problem:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```